# Naming Overlap for Model and API Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have the following code in my Rails app that works fine:

```
last_id ||= 0
status = {status: 'any', fields: 'id,order_number,email,created_at,billing_address,total_price', limit: 250, since_id: last_id}
count = ShopifyAPI::Order.count(status)
```

When I change the first line like this I get an error

```
last_id = Order.find_by_sql("select max(id) from orders where id=#{ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id}")
last_id ||= 0
status = {status: 'any', fields: 'id,order_number,email,created_at,billing_address,total_price', limit: 250, since_id: last_id}
count = ShopifyAPI::Order.count(status)
```

Error:

```
ActiveResource::BadRequest in TestController#index
Failed. Response code = 400. Response message = Bad Request.
Error is on line: count = ShopifyAPI::Order.count(status)
```

Is this a problem because the Shopify API class(?) and the model are named the same? If so, it seems weird that it would work in the first code.

Comment: I don't really think its related to constant lookup - that would give a missing contant or method error.

Comment: Same error, unfortunately

Comment: Have you at least looked at what `last_id` is in the second case? `Order.find_by_sql` isn't going to return a number.

Comment: `Order.find_by_sql` returns an array of `Order` instances. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: last_id isn't being used yet, only created. Should the value of last_id be effecting the count = ... line?

Comment: @Adam12344 it's used in `status` which is passed as an argument to `count`

Comment: But `last_id` **is** being used, there's a `since_id: last_id` in `status` after all.

Comment: You're right, forgot that was in there!

Comment: Got it working with: last_id = Order.find_by_sql("select max(order_id) as order_id from orders where shop_id=#{shop_id}").first.order_id